# Bluetooth on Android Samsung Galaxy XCover always succeeds

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bit of a problem with Android bluetooth connection. I am using bluetooth for printing on Zebra MZ320 printer. So far I did not have any problems with any of mobile phones (printing worked without any problems on Samsung Galaxy Mini, Samsung Galaxy Ace, Samsung Galaxy Nexus S, Samsung Galaxy S2, Samsung Galaxy Nexus S, Samsung Galaxy Note, HTC Desire Z, HTC Desire S, HTC Desire, HTC Legend, HTC Flyer, Samsung Galaxy Tab), however recently i got Samsung Galaxy XCover where printing does not work.

After a day of researching I made this program:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  Button bTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  bTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (new File("/sdcard/logDat.txt").exists()) {
        new File("/sdcard/logDat.txt").delete();
      }
      Toast.makeText(TestPrinterActivity.this, "abcd1234", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      String macAddr = "00:22:58:07:BD:A5";
      //sendCpclOverBluetooth(macAddr);
      BluetoothSocket bSocket = null;
      OutputStream outStream = null;
      InputStream inStream = null;
      try {
        log("try... \tMAC address: "+macAddr);
        BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(macAddr);
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE });
        //Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE });
        bSocket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(device, new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(1) });
        //bSocket = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(macAddr).createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        //bSocket = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(macAddr).createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        log("\tconnect()");
        bSocket.connect();
        log("\tgetOutputStream");
        outStream = bSocket.getOutputStream();
        log("\tgetInputStream");
        inStream = bSocket.getInputStream();
        String cpclData = "! U1 SETLP ARI08ITA.CPF 0 20\r\n test123\r\n";
        // Send the data to printer as a byte array.
        log("\twriting: "+cpclData);
        outStream.write(cpclData.getBytes());
        log("\tflush");
        outStream.flush();
        Sleeper.sleep(1000);
        log("\tfinish1");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log("\t\tERROR: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(TestPrinterActivity.this, "ERROR: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } finally {
        try {
          log("\tbSocket.close");
          bSocket.close();
          log("\toutStream.close");
          outStream.close();
          log("\tinStream.close");
          inStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log("\t\tERROR while closing: "+e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
          Toast.makeText(TestPrinterActivity.this, "ERROR while closing: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
      log("endTry");
    }
  });
}

private void log(String str) {
  if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED ) == false)
    return;
  try {
    BufferedWriter buffWr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/logDat.txt", true));
    buffWr.write(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()) + ": "+ str);
    buffWr.newLine();
    buffWr.close();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(TestPrinterActivity.this, "ERROR writing to log file: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Below are CORRECT and WRONG outputs. Each output contains two scenarios (where printer is on and off).

It seems like on Samsung Galaxy XCover bluetooth always succeeds connecting to the printer even when it is offline...

Any suggestions what to do/try would be greatly appreciated.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  When printer is turned on:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-07-25 14:53:36: try...     MAC address: 00:22:58:07:BD:A5
2012-07-25 14:53:36:    connect()
2012-07-25 14:53:43:    getOutputStream
2012-07-25 14:53:43:    getInputStream
2012-07-25 14:53:43:    writing: ! U1 SETLP ARI08ITA.CPF 0 20
  test123

2012-07-25 14:53:43:    flush
2012-07-25 14:53:44:    finish1
2012-07-25 14:53:44:    bSocket.close
2012-07-25 14:53:44:    outStream.close
2012-07-25 14:53:44:    inStream.close
2012-07-25 14:53:44: endTry

---------------------------------------------------------------------
  When printer is off
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-07-25 14:53:07: try...     MAC address: 00:22:58:07:BD:A5
2012-07-25 14:53:07:    connect()
2012-07-25 14:53:12:        ERROR: Host is down
2012-07-25 14:53:12:    bSocket.close
2012-07-25 14:53:12:    outStream.close
2012-07-25 14:53:12:        ERROR while closing: null
2012-07-25 14:53:12: endTry

Output from Samsung Galaxy XCover (2.3.6):
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  When printer is turned on:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-07-25 15:00:48: try...     MAC address: 00:22:58:07:BD:A5
2012-07-25 15:00:48:    connect()
2012-07-25 15:00:48:    getOutputStream
2012-07-25 15:00:48:    getInputStream
2012-07-25 15:00:48:    writing: ! U1 SETLP ARI08ITA.CPF 0 20
  test123

2012-07-25 15:00:48:    flush
2012-07-25 15:00:49:    finish1
2012-07-25 15:00:49:    bSocket.close
2012-07-25 15:00:49:    outStream.close
2012-07-25 15:00:49:    inStream.close
2012-07-25 15:00:49: endTry

---------------------------------------------------------------------
  When printer is off
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-07-25 15:01:25: try...     MAC address: 00:22:58:07:BD:A5
2012-07-25 15:01:25:    connect()
2012-07-25 15:01:25:    getOutputStream
2012-07-25 15:01:25:    getInputStream
2012-07-25 15:01:25:    writing: ! U1 SETLP ARI08ITA.CPF 0 20
  test123

2012-07-25 15:01:25:    flush
2012-07-25 15:01:26:    finish1
2012-07-25 15:01:26:    bSocket.close
2012-07-25 15:01:26:    outStream.close
2012-07-25 15:01:26:    inStream.close
2012-07-25 15:01:26: endTry
```

Comment: SOLVED: 
I got it working with more delay after write... (but I did not manage to get it working with Zebra library)