# Printing on Zebra MZ220 from Samsung Galaxy XCover

Tags: android

We are trying to print on a Zebra MZ220 from Samsung Galaxy XCover and we get "Unable to determine printer language". From other devices it work fine. Do you have any ideas? Could you post your code sample?

After research we found this https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8239&actp=LIST_RECENT but it only hides the error message, the printer still won't print. There is also this post [Bluetooth on Android Samsung Galaxy XCover always succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651311/bluetooth-on-android-samsung-galaxy-xcover-always-succeeds/15107022#15107022) where a user found the solution but he didn't share it.

Firmware is up to date.

```
 ZebraPrinterConnection thePrinterConn = new BluetoothPrinterConnection(
                              getAdressMac());

                              Looper.prepare();
                              try {
                                    thePrinterConn.open();

                                    ZebraPrinter printer;
                                    printer = ZebraPrinterFactory
                                                  .getInstance(thePrinterConn);
                                    Thread.sleep(500);
                                    Bitmap bitmap = StampilaPrint.getStampila(ctx, Print.this.idSpatiu);
                                    //com.zebra.android.comm.BluetoothPrinterConnection myConn = new com.zebra.android.comm.BluetoothPrinterConnection(macAdd);
                                    //com.zebra.android.printer.ZebraPrinter myPrinter = new com.zebra.android.printer.internal.ZebraPrinterCpcl(myConn); 
                                    printer.getGraphicsUtil().storeImage("IMAGE.PCX",
                                                  bitmap, 215, 215);

                                    printer.getToolsUtil().sendCommand(data);

                                    thePrinterConn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firmware is key with the SDK.  Go to www.zebra.com/firmware and make sure that you have the same firmware as is currently released.  This will solve this problem 99% of the time.

For the other 1% of the time, a little bit of sample code never hurts :)

Comment: There is a little confusion.  The error that you are seeing (Unable to determine printer language) should only be thrown by ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance().  What error are you seeing when you explicitly construct ZebraPrinterCPCL instead of calling getInstance()?